# Get-AzResourceGroup : 'this.Client.SubscriptionId' cannot be null

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

Having a bit of an issue with Azure and Powershell. I'm just checking to see if a resource group exists and I keep hitting this error. The next step after this is to create the resource group if it does not exist, but that is also throwing the same error. Was hoping someone might be able to suggest some workarounds or fixes.

Please note, I have access to the subscriptions, I can see them and sucessfully set the default subscription as can be seen in the script below.

**Full Error Returned**

```
'this.Client.SubscriptionId' cannot be null.
At **********************\envir\create-env.ps1:21 char:1
+ Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup -ErrorVariable $doesNotExist ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzResourceGroup], ValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.GetAzureResourceGroupCmdlet
```

I've just installed the Az module, version details below.

```
Version    Name                                Repository
-------    ----                                ----------
1.6.0      Az                                  PSGallery
```

I'm just running a pretty straight forward script (below), I thought it might be something to do with a default subscription not been set, but setting that has made no difference.

```
$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $servicePrincipalKey -AsPlainText -Force
$pscredential = New-Object 
System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($servicePrincipalUserName, $passwd)
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $pscredential -TenantId $tenantId
Select-AzureSubscription -Default -SubscriptionName $subscriptioName
Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup -ErrorVariable $doesNotExist
```

I then get the error listed above.

Comment: you probably do not have permissions to any subscription?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I can actually see my subscriptions after I authenticate, by using $subs = Get-AzureSubscription.

Comment: do you have azurerm module leftovers? i'd suggest you delete those. what if you skip selecting that particular subscription and just do `get-azresourcegroup`?

Comment: I had already run Uninstall-AzureRm because it warned of conflicts. I also rebooted just in case.
If I comment out the Connect-AzAccount, I still get the same error.,
I also cleared out the Azure profile and tried again from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, the Service Principal I had created did not have sufficient access to the subscription as suggested by @4c74356b41, I ended up giving it a role of Contributor and that resolved the problem.

Comment: Hi @PatrickLu-MSFT, you can't mark your own answer as the answer to a question, someone else has to do that. Kind Regards.